# Какие конфиги писать для MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, centos, config, highload, centos7

Имееться:

- сервер с Centos 7
- на нём установлена MySQL 5.7
- большое количество одновременных запросов
- один запрос на сервер держиться открытым примерно 5-10 минут

Если открыть много вкладок (делать много запросов) то все они зависают и в браузере написанно вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
если это перевести будет так:

```
Ожидаеться доступный сокет...
```

Какой параметр в my.cnf (или в другом файле) нужно менять чтобы эту проблему решить?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что проблема имеет отношение к mysql?

Comment: Вообще, Капитан Очевидность напоминает, что, прежде чем писать какие-то там параметры неважно куда, нужно сперва выяснить точную причину проблемы

Comment: потому что если на этой-же странице убрать работу с бд и подключение - то всё работает быстро

Comment: сервер мощьный, грузиться только на 3-4% - это максимум что было

Comment: Ну так, может, у вас неоптимальные sql-запросы, не расставлены индексы в базе, ещё какие-нибудь ваши личные косяки? Выясните точные место и причину проблемы — тогда и поговорим

Comment: этот же скрипт на сервере который в 4 раза примерно слабее - летал, но там сис-админ конфиги для mysql написал

Comment: индексы есть, запросы тоже правильно написанны

Comment: Но что-то же при этом всё равно тормозит? Вот выясните точное место в коде, которое тормозит, и покажите его нам — тогда и поговорим

Comment: подключение к БД, когда запросов много, есть ограничение написанное в my.cnf поэтому сервер не обрабатывает запросы, а ставит их в очередь

Comment: Ну вот значит сотрите это ограничение из my.cnf, мы-то тут при чём :)

Comment: так что это за ограничение? не могу понять) в этом и был вопрос

Comment: Ну то есть никакого ограничения нет? Ну тогда снова ждём точное место в коде, которое тормозит. До тех пор, пока мы не узнаем, что у вас там на сервере творится, мы ничем помочь не сможем. Не существует такого волшебного my.cnf, который разом решит все проблемы — нужно сперва узнать саму проблему

Comment: ладно, думаю Вы не поняли вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как бросать оптимизировать работу mysql сервера - нужно чётко понимать статистику использования сервера, а не крутить бездумно разные ручки.

Ставите на сервер скрипт Mysqltuner, ждём хотя бы сутки непрерывной работы mysqld, запускаем скрипт и внимательно читаем рекомендации.

Применяем вдумчиво и разборчиво, не крутим за раз больше чем один параметр.

А в текущем виде у вас в вопросе слишком мало информации, советы будут скорее вредными, чем полезными.

Comment: Спасибо, установлю Mysqltuner